# Extract resources to current directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to extract the resources "cygz.dll" to the current directory where the program started right after the form is loaded.

Here is my code.

```
private static void extract(string nameSpace, string outDirectory, string internalFilePath, string resourceName)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

        using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(nameSpace + "." + (internalFilePath == "" ? "" : internalFilePath + ".") + resourceName))

            using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(s))

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outDirectory + "\\" + resourceName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))

                    using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))

                        w.Write(r.ReadBytes((int)s.Length));

    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        extract("myNamespace", "\\TEMP", "resources", "cygz.dll");
    }
```

Instead of "\\TEMP", I want to extract "cygz.dll" to the current directory

Comment: looks like c# code not c

Comment: hint Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: @pm100 Got it.. Using string as for the path. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "current directory" you mean the path for the executable file that started the application, then you can use Application.ExecutablePath like this:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

You can find more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: executablepath != currentdirectory. use Environment.CurrentDirectory for that

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

    extract("myNamespace", path, "resources", "cygz.dll");
}
```

Comment: Note that this could potentially break if the program is started with a different "startup directory" or if it changes to a different one after starting.